# vbscript fileexist error

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to check if file exists/link exists  as follows:  No sucess

Here is my code:

```
filespec = "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"&"\Internet Explorer.lnk"

filespec1 = char(34)&"C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"&"\Internet Explorer.lnk" &char(34)


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (fso.FileExists(filespec)) Then
  msg = filespec & " exists."
Else
  msg = filespec & " doesn't exist."
End If
WScript.Echo(msg)


If (fso.FileExists(filespec1)) Then
  msg = filespec1 & " exists."
Else
  msg = filespec1 & " doesn't exist."
End If
WScript.Echo(msg)
```

None of the above works?  Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Zain

Comment: Do you get any error messages? What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: No I am not getting an error messages at all?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `filespec` vs `filespec1`, but the first problem is `char` is not a VB Script keyword. You need to use `Chr`.

```
filespec1 = Chr(34) & "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs" & "\Internet Explorer.lnk" & Chr(34)
```

### UPDATE 1

This is the code I ran successfully. It is your original code with `char` replaced with `Chr`.

```
filespec = "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"&"\Internet Explorer.lnk"

filespec1 = Chr(34) & "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"&"\Internet Explorer.lnk" & Chr(34)


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (fso.FileExists(filespec)) Then
  msg = filespec & " exists."
Else
  msg = filespec & " doesn't exist."
End If
WScript.Echo(msg)


If (fso.FileExists(filespec1)) Then
  msg = filespec1 & " exists."
Else
  msg = filespec1 & " doesn't exist."
End If
WScript.Echo(msg)
```

Comment: filespect1 and filespec I am checking to see or  make sure file exist and sorry i did use chr(34) still the same issue.

Comment: Is this the complete code or is there more? This code works for me.

Comment: This is the complete code. the only change is in place of C:\Users\xyz, real user name will appear i.e.,  Chr(34) & "c:\Users\realUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs" & "\Internet Explorer.lnk" & Chr(34)